# c# uwp reading more than one value (BLE)

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
private async void CharacteristicReadButton_Click()
        {
             // BT_Code: Read the actual value from the device by using Uncached.
            GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                string formattedResult = FormatValueByPresentation(result.Value, presentationFormat);

                rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read result: {formattedResult}", NotifyType.StatusMessage);  
            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read failed: {result.Status}", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }     
        }
```

I have this problem where whenever I press "read", it justs read one value. I have setup a mpu6050 with my rfduino. So it should read the x , y, z values. However, in my case, it only reads the 'z' value. how do I make it read all three values ?

In my c#: (reads only the z value)
[image]

In my arduino:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks the problem is in FormatValueByPresentation. Value returned as bytes array and the function simple formats it as int or float.

Check your characteristic presentation format first. Then check returned value length.

After that it is possible to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm really new to c# and I need someone to guide me on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Simple try to read characterstic as raw value and check its length.

Comment: Mike, do you have time to slowly guide me on this problem step by step ? Is there anyway I can contact you ?

Comment: where to check its length ?

Comment: Skype: mike.petrichenko